# Java Double calculation between decimal place

Tags: java, double

```
private void fillInState() {
    state [0][0] = 0.6;
    state [0][1] = 0.4;
    state [1][0] = 0.3;
    state [1][1] = 0.6;
    state [1][2] = 0.1;
    state [2][0] = 0.7;
    state [2][2] = 0.3;
}


private void fillInNext() {
    next [0][0] = 1.0;
}

public void chain (int time) { 
    for(int i=0; i<time;i++) {
        for( int j=0; j<3;j++) { 
            double temp = 0;
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++) {
                temp = state[k][j] * next [k][i] + temp;

                if(k==2) {
                    next[j][i+1]=temp;                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*The expected answer should be:*

```
1.0 0.6 0.48  
0.0 0.4 0.48  
0.0 0.0 0.04
```

*But the answer in blueJ is:*

```
1.0 0.6 0.48  
0.0 0.4 0.48  
0.0 0.0 0.04000000000000001
```

Anyone knows what happened? Is that about the Double class or blueJ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

This is simply due to [floating-point errors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). You can always format the output using something like printf:

```
double d = 0.04000000000000001;
System.out.println(d);
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);
```

```
0.04000000000000001
0.04
```

See Oracle's tutorial [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: What if I want to save the result back to the array?

Comment: @user3302184 Then you can just save it normally. The formatting is only for converting the actual double to a visual representation; it has no bearing on the double's value itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how floating point arithmetic works. Try looking at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for some detail. Basically it is not possible to represent arbitrary Decimal numbers in a finite number of binary digits using the normal floating point representation.

If you need your arithmetic to match closely with Decimals then use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Often you can just ignore these errors by rounding the result you output to screen etc.